# Displaying text over image in iCarousel control

Tags: ios, swift, icarousel

I'm attempting to put text on top of a `UIImageView` inside an `iCarousel` control.  There is a sample that does that, and I used the same code as the `func carousel(carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAtIndex index: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView`, with the body being

```
{  
    var itemView: UIImageView
    var name: UILabel
    if (view == nil)  
    {  
        itemView = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 250))  
        itemView.image = ShareData.sharedInstance.accounts[index].getPicture()  
        itemView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit  
        name = UILabel(frame:itemView.bounds)  
        name.backgroundColor = MyVariables.backgroundColor  
        name.textAlignment = .Center  
        name.textColor = MyVariables.outlineColor  
        name.font = name.font.fontWithSize(50)  
        name.tag = 1  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        itemView = view as! UIImageView;  
        name = itemView.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel!  
    }  
    name.text = ShareData.sharedInstance.accounts[index].accountName  
    return itemView  
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Obviously the variables are different, but my code is as identical to the code in the sample as I can get without it not doing what I want.  I have checked and the variable .accountName has the text in it it is supposed to have, so I know that's okay.  Any ideas on what could be wrong with my code would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add  your `UILabel` as a `subview` in `UIImageView` like this

```
if (view == nil)  
{  
    itemView = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 250))  
    itemView.image = ShareData.sharedInstance.accounts[index].getPicture()  
    itemView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit  
    name = UILabel(frame:itemView.bounds)  
    name.backgroundColor = MyVariables.backgroundColor  
    name.textAlignment = .Center  
    name.textColor = MyVariables.outlineColor  
    name.font = name.font.fontWithSize(50)  
    name.tag = 1 

    //You forgot to add this name label in itemView
    itemView.addSubview(name)

}  
else  
{  
    itemView = view as! UIImageView;  
    name = itemView.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel!  
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: When I add this line of code, it gets rid of the picture and just shows the text.  Nice to know the text is there, but I'd really like to see both the picture and the text.  Thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: I figured it out.  I have to change the bounds for the label to be something smaller than the rect for the UIImageView.  That solves the problem.  Between your suggestion, and shrinking the size of the CGRect for the label bounds, I got it to work. =)

Comment: Happy to help ..:)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting label width and height 0,0.

```
 name = UILabel(frame:itemView.bounds)
```

replace it with below line

```
name = UILabel(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 250))
```